# Binding dynamic generated components

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

Jdev version: 11.1.1.7

I created Data control from a Java bean. I bind a jspx page with the data control attributes.

In that page I created components dynamically (forEach loop).

The issue is components only created(incremented) but the binding values is not different.

Code:

Bean:

```
public class ProposalBean
{
  private String name;
  private String age;

  public ProposalBean()
  {
    super();
  }

  public void setName(String name)
  {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public void setAge(String age)
  {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }
}
```

JSPX:

```
<af:form id="f1">

    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1">

      <af:panelTabbed id="pt1">

        <af:forEach var="var" varStatus="vs" begin="1" end="3">

          <af:showDetailItem text="Tab #{vs.index}" id="sdi1">

            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.name.inputValue}"

                          label="#{bindings.name.hints.label}"

                          required="#{bindings.name.hints.mandatory}"

                          columns="#{bindings.name.hints.displayWidth}"

                          maximumLength="#{bindings.name.hints.precision}"

                          shortDesc="#{bindings.name.hints.tooltip}"

                          id="it1">

              <f:validator binding="#{bindings.name.validator}"/>

            </af:inputText>

            <af:inputText value="#{bindings.age.inputValue}"

                          label="#{bindings.age.hints.label}"

                          required="#{bindings.age.hints.mandatory}"

                          columns="#{bindings.age.hints.displayWidth}"

                          maximumLength="#{bindings.age.hints.precision}"

                          shortDesc="#{bindings.age.hints.tooltip}"

                          id="it2">

              <f:validator binding="#{bindings.age.validator}"/>

            </af:inputText>

          </af:showDetailItem>

        </af:forEach>

      </af:panelTabbed>

      <af:commandButton text="submit" id="cb1" action="next"/>

    </af:panelGroupLayout>

  </af:form>
```

Note: In forEach loop end is dynamic.

Comment: as @Nagh says you are missing a serious attribute in your forEach which is the items attribute, it should point to your iterator binding

Answer (score 0):

Because bindings is a merely way to connect view to the model, no magic.

I assume that you have some datasource with iterator.
You have to use this datasource iterator in your foreach loop. And you can use model as datasource or your bean for some cases.

Check this samples:

- [forEach documentation](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_forEach.html)
- [jdevotnharves blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/creating_a_custom_master_detail)